# Linear series on a curve: a question on *degrees*

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let us consider finite morphisms from a nonsingular complex projective curve $C$ to $\mathbb P^r$, where $r\geq 1$ is fixed. So we have to look at ample line bundles $L$ on $C$, and linear subspaces $V\in\textrm{Gr}(r+1,H^0(C,L))$.

In general (e.g. for $r>1$), if $V$ determines $f_V:C\to\mathbb P^r$, then
$$
\deg f_V\neq \deg L\,\,\,(=\deg f_V(C)).
$$
For instance, the embedding of $C=\mathbb P^1$ in $\mathbb P^r$ as a rational normal curve is a morphism of degree $1$ corresponding to a line bundle $L=\mathscr O_C(r)$ of degree $r$.

> **Question.** Is there any numerical relation between $\deg L$ and $\deg f_V$ when $r>1$? Is there any situation (different from $r=1$) when they coincide?

Thank you! (and sorry if this is trivial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P=\mathbb P(V)$ with tautological sheaf $O_P(1)$. Let $C'=f_V(C)$ and suppose $f_V$ is non-constant. By the construction of $f_V$, we have 
$$ L\simeq f_V^*(O_P(1))=g_V^*(O_P(1)|_{C'})$$ 
where $g_V$ is $f_V$ but with $C'$ as target variety. Now $g_V$ is a finite morphism of curves, so 
$$\deg L=\deg g_V\deg (O_P(1)|_{C'})=\deg f_V\deg C'$$ 
where $\deg C'$ is the degree of $C'$ as subvariety of $P$.

From this we see that $\deg L=\deg f_V$ if and only if $C'$ is a line in $P$. This means we can find a basis $e_0, \dots, e_r$ of $V$ such that $e_2, \dots, e_r$ all vanish at $C$. Equivalently, this means $L$ can be generated by two global sections belonging to $V$.